react fullcalendar: extern event - Problem with draggableId in initialView="timeGridWeek"
I am working with React, FullCalendar, and react-beautiful-dnd. I want to drag and drop external tasks into a calendar. The calendar is set to the timeGridWeek view.
My problem is that I can't assign unique droppableId values to the time slots. Currently, every drop event receives the same destination. I would appreciate any guidance on how to resolve this issue.
const handleTaskDrop = async (result) => {
        console.log(result); //in console - destination: draggableId = droppable-calendar 
}

I set this draggableId later in <Droppable droppableId="droppable-calendar"> to assign <fullcalendar>, see later in Calendar.js.
Any help or pointers on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!
Best regards, Thorsten
Here is the code I have so far:
Scheduler.js
import { DragDropContext } from 'react-beautiful-dnd';
[...]
<DragDropContext onDragEnd={handleTaskDrop}>
     <TaskList tasks={tasks} />
     <Calendar
         events={events}
         handleDateClick={handleDateClick}
         handleEventClick={handleEventClick}
         handleEventDrop={handleEventDrop}
         handleEventResize={handleEventResize}
</DragDropContext>

Calendar.js
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/react';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import deLocale from '@fullcalendar/core/locales/de';
import { Droppable, Draggable } from 'react-beautiful-dnd';

const Calendar = ({
events,
        handleDateClick,
        handleEventClick,
        handleEventDrop,
        handleEventResize
        }) => {
    return (
            <Droppable droppableId="droppable-calendar">
                {(provided) => (
                                <div ref={provided.innerRef} {...provided.droppableProps}>
                                    <FullCalendar
                                        plugins={[timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
                                        initialView="timeGridWeek"
                                        timeZone="Europe/Berlin"
                                        editable={true}
                                        selectable={true}
                                        droppable={true}
                                        events={events}
                                        dateClick={handleDateClick}
                                        eventClick={handleEventClick}
                                        eventDrop={handleEventDrop}
                                        eventResize={handleEventResize}
                                        locales={[deLocale]}
                                        locale="de"
                                        slotLabelFormat={{
                                                    hour: '2-digit',
                                                    minute: '2-digit',
                                                    hour12: false
                                                }}
                                        eventTimeFormat={{
                                                    hour: '2-digit',
                                                    minute: '2-digit',
                                                    hour12: false
                                                }}
                                        />
                                    {provided.placeholder}
                                </div>
                                )}
            </Droppable>
            );
};

export default Calendar;

TaskList.js
import { Droppable, Draggable } from 'react-beautiful-dnd';

const TaskList = ({ tasks }) => {
    return (
            <div style={{display: 'flex'}}>
                <Droppable droppableId="droppable-tasks">
                    {(provided) => (
                                <div ref={provided.innerRef} {...provided.droppableProps} style={{ width: '100px' }}>
                                    {tasks.map((task, index) => (
                                                                    <Draggable key={task.id} draggableId={`task-${task.id}`} index={index}>
                                                                        {(provided) => (
                                                                                                                <div
                                                                                                                    ref={provided.innerRef}
                                                                                                                    {...provided.draggableProps}
                                                                                                                    {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                                                                                                                    style={{
                                                                                                                                                    userSelect: 'none',
                                                                                                                                                    padding: '8px',
                                                                                                                                                    margin: '0 0 8px 0',
                                                                                                                                                    backgroundColor: 'lightgrey',
                                                                                                                                                    ...provided.draggableProps.style
                                                                                                                                                }}
                                                                                                                    >
                                                                                                                    {task.name}
                                                                                                                </div>
                                                                                                    )}
                                                                    </Draggable>
                                                                    ))}
                                    {provided.placeholder}
                                </div>
                                    )}
                </Droppable>
            </div>
            );
};

export default TaskList;

